# Adding a custom binding to ToolTip

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro, convention

I am trying to get my head around how the ConventionManager works but I can't seem to figure out how to add a convention to allow for a custom property to be bound.

What I am trying to achieve is that Caliburn.Micro will automagically bind the ToolTip property on a Button to a property in the ViewModel named [Name]ToolTip where [Name] is the name of the button.

Edit:
Seems I accidently used a formatting bracket in my example, oops!

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044051/adding-a-convention-for-isenabled-to-caliburn-micro/9046690#9046690 it's about adding "Enabled convention", I had a quick look on the caliburn.micro source and it seems it's still the way how you need to do it.