# How do I extend the data binding convention in Caliburn.Micro?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I want to extend Caliburn.Micro so it automatically attaches the Enable control to a property on the VM.

Assume I have a `textBox` named `"MyText"` on view.  CM automatically binds it to the `MyText` property on the VM.  I want to extend it so if I define a property in the VM called `"MyTextEnable"`, the `Enable` property of `MyText` automatically binds to it by CM.

How can I do this?  Is there sample code to show how I can extend CM convention? I found nothing in the documentation to help.  I need a sample project to show how to extend it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a convention for IsEnabled to Caliburn.Micro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044051/adding-a-convention-for-isenabled-to-caliburn-micro)