# Caliburn.Micro, Enable textbox based on certain conditions (equivalent for CanExecute for a button)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I've tried to find the answer for some time, but can I enable/disable a textbox using Caliburn.Micro with built-in conventions or do I need to make a custom binding for this feature?

For a button named, e.g. 'Run', I can have a bool property called 'CanRun'. But the same doesn't seem to work for textboxes.

Comment: You can define a new convention, please have a look at the answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9044051/650012) StackOverflow question.