# Blocking UI on click in Caliburn.Micro, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, task, caliburn.micro

How to block UI in `Caliburn.Micro`?

```
public async void AcceptButton()
{
    await this.httpDataService.Register(account);
    Show.SuccesBox(alert);
    this.TryClose();
}
```

How to wait for end of `Task` in my `ViewModel` by blocking `View`?

**EDIT**

i added binding on my button in `xaml`:

```
 IsEnabled="{Binding isEnabled}"
```

Then, my `VM`:

```
bool isEnabled {get;set;}

public async void AcceptButton()
{
    this.isEnabled = false;
    await this.httpDataService.Register(account);
    Show.SuccesBox(alert);
    this.TryClose();
}
```

In this case, `AcceptButton` is always unactive `IsEnabled=false`. How to trigger `false` only on button click?

Comment: Do you want to prevent the user to do anything else during the running process?

Comment: Yes, i want to block whole app

Comment: "How to block UI" - the correct answer is "you don't." Why do you want to?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/explaing-icommand-in-mvvm-wpf/

Comment: @StephenCleary because i dont want to user double-tap "Send form" button

Comment: I dont know why someone downvoted my question. Its uniqe in Stack Overflow scale and someone can  have similar problems like i have

Comment: If it is only one button that you want to disable you really should have a look at the mvvm pattern

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18617959/disabling-multiple-controls-depending-on-a-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because i dont want to user double-tap "Send form" button

The standard way of doing that is just disabling the button. Or, if you want to disable the entire form, then disable the entire window:

```
public async void AcceptButton()
{
  this.IsEnabled = false;
  await this.httpDataService.Register(account);
  Show.SuccesBox(alert);
  this.TryClose();
}
```

You should add the `IsEnabled` property to your view model class and then bind it to the `IsEnabled` property of the view.

Disabling the window is nicer to the user than an unresponsive application, because this approach allows the user to minimize it or move it out of the way if it is taking an unexpectedly long time.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but i mentioned `Caliburn.Micro` in my thread because im using this framework for my views. Because of that, i cant block my button as you mention, because `IsEnabled` is undefined in caliburn;s `ViewModels`

Comment: @michasaucer: You should add the `IsEnabled` property yourself to your view model class and then bind it to the `IsEnabled` property of the view. Don't fortget to set it back to true once the task has completed.

Comment: Thanks! I added `Binding = ButtonEnableState` to my button on `IsEnabled`, i make property in `VM` class and it works! Please edit your answer so you will help someone in future :)

Comment: I have a little problem, i make property like yours (`IsEnabled` with `get, set`), i set it to false on `AcceptButton` but on window launch, it is set to `false` (before i clicked on my button). Can you tell me, how to trigger `false` ONLY when i click the button, not before?

Comment: @StephenCleary could you look on my `edit` in original post?

Comment: @michasaucer: Set the property to `true` by default: `bool isEnabled {get;set;} = true;`

Comment: @mm8 now i can click on button (and it works) but its not change to `false` when i click on `AcceptButton` (its stays on `true`)

Comment: @michasaucer: You need to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the property after you've set it: `this.NotifyOfPropertyChange( () => this.IsEnabled );`